# Add a label in UIAlertController?

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

I know that you can add a text field, but is it possible to add a label to a `UIAlertController`?

```
alertController.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler({(textField: UITextField!) in
            textField.placeholder = "Hyperlink"
            inputTextField = textField
            inputTextField?.text="www.google.com"
        })
```

^^Textfield

Comment: can you show which type of output do u need

Comment: Why do you wanna add a custom label?

Comment: I'm trying to add a hyperlink url, and the way I know how to do it is with a label

Comment: @Snorlax I know it doesn't really answer the question, but could you display the hyperlink as the Alert's message, and then add an action that opens the url?

Answer (score 0):

There is function for you:

```
  func showAlertWith(withLabel: String) {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Hello!", message: "Hi everybody!\n", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert )
    let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default)
    alert.addAction(action)
    
    present(alert, animated: true, completion: {
      //  Add your label
      let margin:CGFloat = 8.0
      let rect = CGRect(x: margin, y: 72.0, width: alert.view.frame.width - margin * 2.0 , height: 20)
      let label = UILabel(frame: rect)
      label.text = withLabel
      label.textAlignment = .center
      label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
      label.minimumScaleFactor = 0.5
      alert.view.addSubview(label)
    })
  }
```

I didn't bother too much with the coordinates and options of the label inside the alert, but I think that the general meaning is clear to you.

Answer (score -1):

This may solve your issue in much easier and flexible way.
https://github.com/wimagguc/ios-custom-alertview

The addSubview is not available in UIAlertView since iOS7. The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified.

As a solution, this class creates an iOS-style dialog which you can extend with any UIViews or buttons. The animations and the looks are copied too and no images or other resources are needed.

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add context around the link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Take into account that being barely more than a link to an external site is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: @FelixSFD Did you went through the link ? Description and screenshots are present there. i don't know why it was marked as negative ?

Comment: Please read my comment carefully and have a look at this meta post: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259

Comment: still no need to mark it negative as provided answer is right and description and  is provided with  in the link.
the asked question is a small and simple api so as the answer.

Comment: its a whole code. what you expect me to paste here ?
i can post the description at max but cant post the whole code.
there are thousands of posts where links are given for code download. should they all attach/post the whole code ?

Comment: It will be great to post a sample code using this api to solve the original issue

Comment: @YuryFedorov would you mind removing your -ve marking now ?
i can show you a lot of examples where right answers are present with links only. and just sharing the calling code doesnt make any sense when the code itself is on some other place.

Comment: @YuryFedorov just go through the comments history. you marked a down vote but i think later on you removed it. although i dont have the mechanism to track.